# How to get the value when the first 2 loops are completed

Tags: python, for-loop

If I want to get the value when the last loop completed,I can use `last_a=a`

But how to get the value when the first 2 loops are completed

Input:

```
A=[20,13,15,25,24,17,14,19,23,11]
B=[32,43,65,21,13,16,53,52,35,38]
last_a=last_b=0
last_last_a=0
last_last_b=0
for a,b in zip(A, B):
    if a<last_a and b<last_b:
        pass
    last_a=a
    last_b=b
    print(last_last_a)
```

Expected Output

```
0
0
20
13
15
25
24
17
14
19
```

Comment: You're not updating `last_last_a` in your loop (nor `last_last_b`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `last_last_a = last_a` before assigning to `last_a`. Also, you need to print before making those assignments, as these assignments serve for the *next* iteration of the loop. So:

```
for a,b in zip(A, B):
    if a<last_a and b<last_b:
        pass
    print(last_last_a)    # moved up
    last_last_a = last_a  # <-- added
    last_a=a
    last_b=b
```

As you don't print `last_last_b`, there is no need for that name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` with `zip`
to keep track.

And then just use required index.

```
for index, (name, age) in enumerate(zip(names, ages)):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the value after two loops, just track the loops with a variable like `i`. However, if you want a value

> after the first 2 loops are completed

you will not get a list as written in expected Output but one value (or more if you add print statements). I think your logic is off, since `last_last_a` is never modified.

```
A=[20,13,15,25,24,17,14,19,23,11]
B=[32,43,65,21,13,16,53,52,35,38]
last_a=last_b=0
last_last_a=0
last_last_b=0
for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
    if a<last_a and b<last_b:
        pass
    last_a=a
    last_b=b
    if i==2:
        print(last_last_a)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).